# Error when adding a prefix to a **variable** from @use with @forward

Tags: sass

Receiving an error while using a prefix on a **variable** imported using @use with a @forward, however using a prefix on a mixin works as expected.

Note: I've also tried to replace'-' with '_', '' and desperately removed the '$' which I figured would never work. No success.

> This is written @forward "" as -*, and it adds the given
>   prefix to the beginning of every mixin, function, and variable name
>   forwarded by the module
>   - cite: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward

## Use case

*_colors.scss*

```
// Variable.
$primary-color-var: red;

// Mixin.

@mixin primary-color-mixin-example {
  $primary-color: red;
}
```

*_all-modules.scss*

```
@forward './colors' as colors-*;
```

*sample-component.scss*

```
@use '../modules/all-modules' as foo;



.sample-component {
  @include  foo.colors-primary-color-mixin-example; // Works.
}



.sample-component {
  color : foo.colors-$primary-color-var; // Throws an error.

}
```

### Error message

```
Error: expected "(".
  ╷
6 │   color : colors.fonts-$primary-color-var;
  │                     ^
  ╵
  src/sass/components/sample-component.scss 6:21  root stylesheet
```

### Additional context

I would prefer not to use a mixin because I would like to assign the imported variable to a local variable, which doesn't seem to be possible when @including a mixin;
`$local-primary-color: foo.colors-$primary-color-var;`

Comment: For this specific scenario I'd instead use `@import` since you're just needing vars anyway.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in @ChrisW. The documentation seems to say it's possible so I''m assuming it's a bug. I should have mentioned that I also want to create a local variable that references the imported one.  `$local-color: foo.colors-$primary-color-var` which @include doesn't allow.

Comment: Ya so what I generally do is create a file just for vars and `@import` it into other files that are needed and keep vars, functions, mixins, all separate since none are transpiled. Then where in this instance you need the var, you `@import` and if you have say a local var on the receiving file just chain it `$new-var: $original-var-to-inherit-from`. Personally I avoid @forward because it can make maintenance on large solutions a real pain if over-used.